# Can't change textsize and text color for listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change textsize and textcolor for listview. I do:
+ I create new xml file (mytext.xml) in folder layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:id="@android:id/text1"  
          android:paddingTop="2dip" 
          android:paddingBottom="3dip" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and i change :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.mytext,HistoryList);
```

But eclipse can't find mytext.xml?

Comment: if everything in your code is right, then go to Project menu and clean your project. But make sure that everything should be fine before doing this. Else you may loose your R.java file from gen folder

Comment: "android.R.layout.mytext" this line should be "R.layout.mytext"

Comment: @user1609578 Post your full code and are you using custom listview?

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.mytext, HistoryList);
```

In the above line the second parameter for the `ArrayAdapter` should be **R.layout.mytext** instead of **android.R.layout.mytext**.

Comment: you can search google for color codes.you can change the textsize with android:textsize attribute and color with android:textcolor attribute for your textview in your mytext.xml.